# Angular material - Affix

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular 4 with angular material 2.0.0-beta.12.

I want to achieve something that's called "affix~" on [angular material website](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview)

I need to build something like this image:

[image]

that, while scrolling, these items will be "active" if the content is beeing seen on the page. Each item will have an anchor as well.

Anyone knows an easy and clean way to do it?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The Angular Material website is on Github. You can just look at its code.

Comment: It's called a table of contents. For more info, see the source code for `<table-of-contents>` here: https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/b029f9108d4c89ce4dd75cffaaf4ea9d365dcc70/src/app/shared/table-of-contents/table-of-contents.ts and https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/7d0297bb64f70625b5117d999839acb14143087f/src/app/shared/table-of-contents/table-of-contents.html. It also uses `position: sticky` to make it "stick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create from scratch you can follow the tutorial:

https://oliverveits.wordpress.com/2017/07/18/angular-4-automatic-table-of-contents/

It explains how to create a two-level automatic Table of Contents. You can clone the code by doing the following:

```
# git clone https://github.com/oveits/ng-universal-demo
# cd ng-universal-demo
# git checkout 8ca27d5   # to be sure you are working with exact same that has been created in this blog
```

Also you can use the material angular table of contents https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/b029f9108d4c89ce4dd75cffaaf4ea9d365dcc70/src/app/shared/table-of-contents

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is divided into three parts:
1. The rightmost menu which changes on scrolling. Those are links when clicked point to that position on the same page.

```
<a href="#NestedList">Nested List</a>
```

Now you create the actual link. Nested List in this example.

```
<a name="NestedList">Nested List with details </a>
```

Now for highlighting the text using css or angular you can check if the div is present in the browser window. Then just highlight whichever you find first starting from the top.

> **Note:** Name and Href have a difference of only 1 char **#** (pound). This is a necessity.